# Mongo indexes when searching on one value, sorting on another

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I've started to get a hang of proper indexing in Mongo, but there's one thing I'm a bit confused on.

If I want to search on one field (level) and sort on another (random), how do I setup that index? Which field comes first?

Note: Above, by random, I mean I have a field called random. I am not sorting on a randomly selected field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting on "random" field in mongodb is not a good idea. If sort is not indexed, then sorting will be done in memory, which is a problem for a large result sets.

An index can support sort operations on a non-prefix subset of the index key pattern. To do so, the query must include equality conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys. So if your index is { a : 1, b : 1} you can have query like this

> db.data.find( { a: "foo" } ).sort( { b: 1 } )

Mongobd documentation explains it well: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Edit:  Based on updated question your index should be  { level : 1, random : 1}

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a field called random that has a random value as to create a random ordering. I'll clarify in the OP. But thanks for the answer. Basically, always index from largest set to smallest?

Comment: In that case your index should be { level : 1, random : 1} but make sure that your query includes equality on level. In order for sort to use index the part before "sort" must be included in the query. So if you have index { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1} the queries db.data.find( a : "foo", b : "bar").sort( { c : 1} ) and db.data.find( a : "foo").sort( { b : 1} )  will use index but the query db.data.find( a : "foo").sort( { c : 1} ) will not use index and will have to sort in memory.